# Perl, dereference array of references

Tags: perl, arrays, reference

In the following Perl code, I would expect to be referencing an array reference inside an array

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @a=([1,2],[3,4]);

my @b = @$a[0];

print $b[0];
```

However it doesn't seem to work. I would expect it to output 1.

`@a` is an array of references

`@b` is `$a[1]` dereferenced (I think)

So what's the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This stuff is tricky.

`@$a[0]` is parsed as `(@$a)[0]`, dereferencing the (undefined) scalar `$a`

You wanted to say `@{$a[0]}`.

Comment: there's so many quirks in Perl I'm still getting used to. thanks for your help

Comment: When in doubt, just add more braces :D